# Looping through child elements in Twig 2.10 without using if

Tags: theming

Currently I need to loop through child elements in my Twig to render dynamic grids properly. I have achieved this by using code similar to this

```
{% for key, child in element if key|first != '#' %}
  <div>{{ child }}</div>
{% endfor %}
```

This works exactly how I am needing it to work. However in Twig 2.10 using an `if` inside of a `for` is now deprecated and it is now recommended to use either a `filter` filter or an `if` inside the body of the `for`.

> Using an "if" condition on "for" tag in "main.twig" at line 1 is
> deprecated since Twig 2.10.0, use a "filter" filter or an "if"
> condition inside the "for" body instead (if your condition depends on
> a variable updated inside the loop).

I have been unable to figure out how to achieve the same effect using the `filter` filter in this case and could use some help with the change. I'm sure I'm making some basic error but my brain isn't solving this one quickly.

Comment: The error message says it all already. Use just the for loop. And inside it use the standalone if condition. Not for-if, endfor but for, if, your markup, endif, endfor. That's all.

Comment: I did try this and it worked for most things, however with how some of my custom blocks are set up it would end up throwing errors so I wasn't sure if there were other options.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can install the [Twig Tweak](https://www.drupal.org/project/twig_tweak) module and use the [`children`](https://www.drupal.org/docs/contributed-modules/twig-tweak-2x/cheat-sheet#s-children-filter) filter it provides.

For example:

```
{% for child in element|children %}
  <div>{{ child }}</div>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Wow that made my life fantastically better and drastically simpler. Thanks sonfd.